# how to navigate to homescreen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I wonder how can I navigate from one screen to the homepage screen in futter. I created a route for the home screen ('/'), and then added a function to the arrow button so it pop the home screen, but the 'context' appears with a problem and underlined in a red line.

```
 Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onPressed: () {
                            moveHome();
                            },
                          ),




void moveHome() {
   Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

The problem is in the context of this Navigator.pop(context);

Thnk

Comment: It appears with a redline because context is not a local variable or method parameter and the compiler cannot pick it up on its own. Your build function where you create the Row widget should have access to context, pass it to the moveHome function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move back 1 screen to Home screen, then add context to function moveHome().

If you want to move from any place to Home screen, try [pushReplacement](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html). However, it will remove all your previous route.